# Angular/PrimeNG - dropdown empty

Tags: angular, dropdown, empty, primeng

Galera estou com um problema ao utilizar o componente  dropdown do primeNG versão 10.

tenhho uma lista que está dessa forma:
listaSexos = ['Masculino', 'Feminino']

porém quando eu vou utilizar o dropDown a lista aparece como empty, já tentei usar o optionLabel mas ainda não deu certo.

<p-dropdown
[options]="listaSexos">